# How to use JQuery contains for exact string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could jQuery contains used for select exact string?

Here is a working code for setting the row colour in every table row which contains the string tree.

```
$( "#AnsprechpartnerTabelle tr:contains('" + x + "')").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

The problem is that rows which has "treeapple" as content are selected too.

So how could it build that it works like the userstory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$("#AnsprechpartnerTabelle tr").filter(function() {
return $(this).text() === x;
}).css( "background-color", "red" );
```